# Attachment trigger work not persisting

Tags: trigger, attachment

i am trying to append the case id to attachment using trigger i have written correct logic but not getting any error and not appending case id to the attachment

here is my code

Trigger:

trigger AttachmentTrigger on Attachment (after insert,after update) {

```
AttachmentTriggerHandler handler = new AttachmentTriggerHandler();

if(Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)){
    handler.appendingCaseNumberToAttachment(trigger.new);
```

}

}

Handler :

/*public class AttachmentTriggerHandler {

```
public void  appendingCaseNumberToAttachment(list<Attachment> attaches){

    list<Attachment> listOfAttachments = new list<Attachment>();
    set<Id> parentIds = new set<Id>();
    for(Attachment newAttachments:attaches){
        system.debug('attaches====>'+newAttachments);
        if(((String)newAttachments.ParentID).startswith('500')){
            parentIds.add(newAttachments.ParentID);
            System.debug('parentIds===='+parentIds);

        }
        }
        Map<id,Case> casemap=new map<Id,Case>([select id,CaseNumber,(SELECT id,Name from Attachments) from case where id IN:parentIds]);
        for(Case cc:casemap.values()){
        for(Attachment attach:cc.Attachments){
            System.debug('Attachments========'+attach);
            attach.name=cc.CaseNumber+'-'+attach.Name;
            listOfAttachments.add(attach);
            //Attachments.Name = Attachments.Name+'-'+Attachments.(case.id).ParentId;

        }
       } 

}
```

}*/

public class AttachmentTriggerHandler {

```
public void  appendingCaseNumberToAttachment(list<Attachment> attaches){

    list<Attachment> listOfAttachments = new list<Attachment>();
    set<Id> parentIds = new set<Id>();
    for(Attachment newAttachments:attaches){
        system.debug('attaches====>'+newAttachments);
        if(((String)newAttachments.ParentID).startswith('500')){
            parentIds.add(newAttachments.ParentID);
            System.debug('parentIds===='+parentIds);

        }
    }


    Map<id,Case> casemap=new map<Id,Case>([select id,CaseNumber,(SELECT id,Name from Attachments) from case where id IN:parentIds]);
    for(Case cc:casemap.values()){
        for(Attachment attach:cc.Attachments){
            System.debug('Attachments========'+attach);
            attach.name=cc.CaseNumber+'-'+attach.Name;
            listOfAttachments.add(attach);
            //Attachments.Name = Attachments.Name+'-'+Attachments.(case.id).ParentId;

        }
    }

   update listOfAttachments;
}
```

}

Please suggest me where i am doing mistake

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. It's good that you've included your code (really hard to find issues without that). It'd also be helpful to include the code for the trigger that calls this `AttachmentTriggerHandler` class. It could be that you simply need to add a DML statement, but it's hard to say if you need that (or if that'd even fix your problem) without seeing the trigger too.

Comment: @salesforce crm - on what object is this trigger firing ? what is the trigger event ?

Comment: You need to avoid performing queries inside a loop - you query the cases in a loop over the attachments. If called from a trigger, you may get 200 attachments into a single trigger invocation and exceed your permitted number of query operations.

Comment: The main reason this isn't working is because you update the "cc.Attachments" which are queried separately. You are not updating the actual input attachments.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with your code. The first one is a big no-no. You have a `SELECT` statement inside of your `for` loop. This will potentially hit [governor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm) if your trigger fires with a sufficiently large number of records.

The second is that you never persist your changes to the database.

This is a potential correct code for you.

```
public class AttachmentTriggerHandler {

    public void  appendingCaseNumberToAttachment(list<Attachment> attaches){

        list<Attachment> listOfAttachments = new list<Attachment>();
        set<Id> parentIds = new set<Id>();
        for(Attachment newAttachments:attaches){
            system.debug('attaches====>'+newAttachments);
            if(((String)newAttachments.ParentID).startswith('500')){
                parentIds.add(newAttachments.ParentID);
                System.debug('parentIds===='+parentIds);

            }
        }


        Map<id,Case> casemap=new map<Id,Case>([select id,CaseNumber,(SELECT id,Name from Attachments) from case where id IN:parentIds]);
        for(Case cc:casemap.values()){
            for(Attachment attach:cc.Attachments){
                System.debug('Attachments========'+attach);
                attach.name=cc.CaseNumber+'-'+attach.Name;
                listOfAttachments.add(attach);
                //Attachments.Name = Attachments.Name+'-'+Attachments.(case.id).ParentId;

            }
        }

       update listOfAttachments;
    }
}
```

The code above assumes you're running in an `after` context. If you are in a `before` context, you wouldn't need to use `listOfAttachments` and you could update the `attaches` list directly (with no need for DML) to see the attachment names updated.

PS: As Phil pointed out, if this is an `Attachment` trigger, you may run into exceptions while trying to update the records already in the trigger. But without seeing your code and getting more info about your logic I am hesitant to update the code any further.

Comment: Note that there is an implication that the handler is called from a trigger, so the update at the end is plain wrong. What must be done is to update the attachments in the input "attaches" list instead (a DML is then not needed). Update your answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: It is most definitely not "plain wrong" if this is an "after" trigger, as stated in my answer. There could be good reasons for this and, since the OP has not provided neither context nor detail, I cannot assume that this code was meant to run in the "before" and therefore stuck as close as I can to the code that was provided.

Comment: You can't update the trigger objects themselves in the after phase. You will get an exception.

Comment: Now you're assuming the trigger is on the attachment object. Which I can't do. Once proper detail is provided, I will be happy to adjust my code to what the OP's scenario looks like.

Comment: That's a fair point except the title says "Attachment trigger".

Comment: I've seen some things in my life, dude. :-) I'm sure you've seen the same. "Assume nothing" is my motto.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96761/discussion-between-phil-w-and-sebastian-kessel).

Comment: i have added trigger and it's handler too and as Sebastian Kessel said it's my mistake to put query inside the loop but now everything is fine but stills it's throwing below error.

 
Error: Apex trigger sales_force_crm.AttachmentTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: sales_force_crm.AttachmentTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00P2v00001wjgixEAA; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY,